# Ocorre o erro undefined variable quando uso classes

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma conexão com o firebird através de uma class PHP, utilizando o PDO, no entanto ele está ocorrendo um erro bem sinistro no qual eu me perdi, observem  as páginas, index.php / conectar.php  e a class.

INDEX.PHP

```
require("conectar.php");   
$sql = "SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019";
$stmt = $lokos->query($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($itens !== false)
    {  foreach($itens as $row) {
            echo  "<span>".$row['NOMCLI']."</span>";
        }
    }
```

Conectar.php

```
require("conectarDuosig.class.php");
$duo = new Duosig();
$duo->host = "127.0.0.1";
$duo->user = "SYSDBA";
$duo->pass = "masterkey";
$duo->dbnome = "127.0.0.1:DCOL";
$duo->conecta();
```

conectarDuosig.class.php

```
class Duosig{
         // variaveis para a conexão
     public $host;
     public $user;
     public $pass;
     public $dbnome;
         // função para conectar
     function conecta(){
          $lokos=new PDO("firebird:localhost=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbnome",$this->user, $this->pass);
     }
}
```

Quando eu faço com a class ele da erro na linha 21 que no caso é a

```
  $stmt = $lokos->query($sql);
```

Porém quando eu faço a conexão pura, direto no código fonte

indo la e colocar

```
$lokos=new PDO("firebird:localhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=127.0.0.1:DCOL", $pass, $user);
```

e faço o select, ele puxa normal.

Comment: Poderia informar o erro que ocorre?

Comment: Notei que você tem várias respostas que lhe resolveram o seu problema, mas você não marcou nenhuma como "correta", sugiro que faça o tour para entender como funciona o site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour . A comunidade agradece.

Comment: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635)

Comment: Por favor @EdwardJunior, manifeste-se aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4067/132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que `$lokos` é uma variável privada de `conecta()` ou seja não é acessível fora do método, para pegar a conexão o jeito mais simples seria apenas adicionar `return` em `conectar()`.

```
function conecta(){
   return new PDO(...);
}
```

No INDEX.php

```
require("conectar.php");   

$lokos = $duo->conecta();

$sql = "SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019";
$stmt = $lokos->query($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($itens !== false)
    {  foreach($itens as $row) {
            echo  "<span>".$row['NOMCLI']."</span>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você ignorou as regras de herança do Objeto neste caso, pois você só pode chamar um método do PDO através da sua classe só depois que ele for instanciado dentro dela. Verifique também os métodos privados e públicos do objeto PDO que você está chamando.

Experimente fazer assim:

```
<?php

class ConexaoDatabase
{

 private static $servidor = '127.0.0.1'; // Servidor, no caso poderia ser também localhost
 private static $usuario = 'SYSDBA'; // usuário do banco de dados
 private static $senha = 'masterkey'; // senha do banco de dados
 private static $banco = '127.0.0.1:DCOL'; // nome do banco de dados
 private static $instance = null;

 public static function getConnection()
 {
     if (!self::$instance instanceof PDO) {
        try {
             self::$instance = new PDO('firebird:localhost=' . 
             self::$servidor . ';dbname=' . 
             self::$banco, 
             self::$usuario, 
             self::$senha, 
             array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            echo "Erro ao conectar :: {$exc->getMessage()}";
        }
     }
 return self::$instance;
 }

 public function fetchAll($query)
 {
    $con = self::getConnection();
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $this->execute($stmt);

    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
       return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

 public function fetch($query)
 {
    $con = self::getConnection();
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $this->execute($stmt);

    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
       return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

 public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null)
 {
    try {
          if (isset($data)) {
             $stmt->execute($data);
          } else {
            $stmt->execute();
          }
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
          echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
          var_dump($exc->getMessage());
    }
 }

 /** 
  UPDATE OR INSERT DATA
 **/
 public function save($sql, array $data)
 {
    $con = self::getConnection();
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $this->execute($stmt, $data);
    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

}

?>
```

Para chamar o método:

```
$conexao = new ConexaoDatabase();
$sql = "SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019";
$itens = $conexao->fetchAll($sql);
if ($itens !== false) {
    foreach ($itens as $row) {
      echo "<span>".$row->NOMCLI."</span>\n";
    }
}
```